# PHP in_array() Bringing Back Incorrect Result

Tags: php, arrays

I'm very new to PHP so please go easy on me. This problem has had me bemused for a couple of hours now so I thought I would swallow my pride and come to you guys in hope that you can see why this could be a problem.

I have an array which I have converted from an object array with the following code:

```
$category_tree = $client->catalogCategoryTree($session_id); // Get an object array of all categories and assign to $category_tree.
$category_list = (array) $category_tree; // Convert $category_tree into an array and assign to $category_list.
```

This outputs as the following when using `print_r($category_list)`:

```
Array
(
    [category_id] => 1
    [parent_id] => 0
    [name] => Root Catalog
    [position] => 0
    [level] => 0
    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [category_id] => 2
                    [parent_id] => 1
                    [name] => Root Category
                    [is_active] => 1
                    [position] => 1
                    [level] => 1
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [category_id] => 8
                                    [parent_id] => 2
                                    [name] => Designer
                                    [is_active] => 1
                                    [position] => 1
                                    [level] => 2
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [category_id] => 7
                                    [parent_id] => 2
                                    [name] => Shop Bags
                                    [is_active] => 1
                                    [position] => 2
                                    [level] => 2
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [category_id] => 5
                                    [parent_id] => 2
                                    [name] => DifferentCategory
                                    [is_active] => 1
                                    [position] => 3
                                    [level] => 2
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [category_id] => 6
                                                    [parent_id] => 5
                                                    [name] => 1
                                                    [is_active] => 1
                                                    [position] => 1
                                                    [level] => 3
                                                    [children] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [3] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [category_id] => 4
                                    [parent_id] => 2
                                    [name] => Sample Category
                                    [is_active] => 1
                                    [position] => 6
                                    [level] => 2
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

When I am testing for if a string exists within this array using `in_array()`, the result is telling me that it does exist within the string, despite it not doing. Please see the code below for this:

```
$string = 'Chanel';
if (in_array($string, $category_list)) {
    echo 'The string is in the array';
} else {
    echo 'The string is not in the array';
}
```

This outputs:

`The string is in the array`

But it isn't (as you can see from the array output above).

Thank you in advance for any insight you can offer this new guy :)

Comment: Try using strict type comparison http://nl1.php.net/in_array, currently `'string == 0'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there is some type coercion going on. When php has to compare the string `Chanel` with an integer, it does some type conversions to arrive at the result. It seems you would rather this not happen. Fortunately, there is a 3rd optional argument to [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) which controls whether the types must match as well as the values.

Try changing:

```
if (in_array($string, $category_list)) {
```

to

```
if (in_array($string, $category_list, true)) {
```

Comment: This now works if `$string` is not in the array but after testing for a positive result, it seems that it's only working if I change the value of `$string` to `Root Catalog` which exists in the top level of the array output from my post. I tested with `Designer` which is further nested and was told that it does not exist within the array. Is it possible that it cannot access the nested arrays here? Should I possibly look at an alternative method of converting the initial object array or find another way around this? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe something to do with the `stdClass Objects` of those? Do I possibly need to convert to array twice?

Comment: [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) doesn't recurse into nested arrays. Write a recursive function to do that yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.